Pulp Optimization with Decision Variable as Boundary
I am currently working on a linear programming problem using the Pulp library in Python. The problem involves optimizing the capacity of a battery, which is represented as a decision variable in my model. However, I face an issue when one decision variable acts as a boundary for another.  Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:
from pulp import LpProblem, LpMinimize, LpVariable, lpSum, PULP_CBC_CMD

problem = LpProblem("BatteryOptimization", LpMinimize)
battery_capacity_kwh = LpVariable("battery_capacity", 0, 100, cat="Continuous")
other_variable = LpVariable("other_variable", 0, battery_capacity_kwh, cat="Continuous")
# other_variable = LpVariable("other_variable", 0, 100, cat="Continuous")
problem += other_variable <= battery_capacity_kwh

costs = [other_variable * j for j in range(-10, 10)]
problem += lpSum(costs)
problem.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))

print(f"Optimal Battery Capacity: {battery_capacity_kwh.varValue} kWh")
print(f"Optimal Value of Other Variable: {other_variable.varValue}")

In this code, battery_capacity_kwh is a decision variable, and other_variable is another decision variable bounded by battery_capacity_kwh. The objective function is to minimize the sum of other_variable multiplied by a range of numbers.
The issue I am facing is that Pulp does not seem to optimize problems where a decision variable acts as a boundary for another decision variable. I would expect the optimizer to adjust both battery_capacity_kwh and other_variable to minimize the objective function, but this does not seem to be the case.

Is it possible to write your problem as a math model rather than a script? It gives more chance to elaborate community members.

There's nothing wrong with this:
battery_capacity_kwh = LpVariable("battery_capacity", 0, 100, cat="Continuous")
other_variable = LpVariable("other_variable", 0, 100, cat="Continuous")
problem += other_variable <= battery_capacity_kwh

Just as a note on terminology.  PuLP does not optimize problems, it is not a solver.  It is a framework which allows you to model optimization problems which is then passed to a solver.  I'd be surprised if there were any frameworks or solver APIs which permitted a variable as an upper bound argument in the way that you tried.

Well, what could be improved is a warning or error message that what I attempted will not work. As it is, it fails silently. It is up to the user to decide whether that is wrong.
By the way, thank you for clarifying the terminology. As you can tell, this is not my area of expertise.
